# Automated testing of a SOAP Service

Tags: web-services, soap

Before just answering: Use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Please read the Question, because I tried `SoapUI`.

I have a lot big `wsdl` Files. Every Method works like this:
First do a `synchronous Call`:

- Request: Please do `foo` and send Request to `URI: XY`
- Response: Ok, your Job has `UUID: abc`

After the Job is done, my Sevice will respond to `URI: XY`, by sending only a `request` Message synchronously:

- Request: Ok I finished your Job with the `UUID: abc` and the result is `bar`

We needed to use this behavior, because we have a pool where all answers will be stored and are identified by `UUID`.

Do you know a possibility to test such a SOAP Service?

I tried:

- SOAP UI
- BPEL Unit (I think it should be possible with BPEL Unit but I can't make it work properly)

Please don't recommend writing my own `JAVA` tests, because I have more than 100 methods to test.

**Also the Tests need to be run and the results need to be analyzed automatically in a Test-suite, I can't do this for 100 Methods by hand everytime I change the code of the Web Service.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the SoapUI Guys, so you'll probably HATE my answer...

But the solution is using SoapUI; more specifically using MockResponse TestSteps. SoapUI is NOT very strong when it comes to BPEL testing, but using MockResponse Steps you can fix it.

Look here: http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/testing-asynchronous-services.html. Even though all calls are done synchronously, this can still be considered asynch testing since we have more than plain request/response.

I also know that Oracle has got a great write up on this.

Comment: Actually I love your Answer, because this works :) Thank you very much for helping me out. I'm also interested in the Oracle Paper if you would have a link or a name?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a mock service that will receive the second call which signals that the job processing is done. This is can be done in SOAP UI, you can read about how to create a mock web-service [here](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html).

Comment: I know about Mock Services. But you can't test the results you receive in the Mock Service automatically, as far as I am concerned. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can test Web Services by using Eclipse.

**Just put the WSDL file on your project -> right click on the file -> web services -> test using web service explorer.**

You will have an interface showing all your WSDL operations and fields which are needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need this tests to be automated. Just invoking a Soap method, will work with no problems in Soap UI. Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: @Robin You can sdo this using Eclipse -> right click on your WSDL file -> generate client.  This will create all the classes you need in Java code giving you a web service client in which you can set parameters and cal the service as much times as you want

Comment: @Michael Hi! Can you point me to some guide about using the generated client?